# Could not download common.jar (com.android.tools:common:25.2.3): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio

The project was working fine till yesterday. Today I am getting this error. The project is unable to sync.

Comment: untick offline sync in android studio

Comment: this is working.thanks